# Why is it okay for the central carbon to lose a bond when forming a resonance structure for acetone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance, hybridization, lewis-structure

As the title reads, I'm confused as to why it's okay for the central carbon in acetone to have a +1 formal charge when we push the electrons from one of the bonds with oxygen to form a lone pair and give the oxygen a -1 formal charge.

Comment: Try to read this question after a month, pretending it was written by someone else, if it is still clear to you after a single look.

Comment: Resonance structures are a model, and as such, it may or may not reflect reality. It's only as good as the predictions are. Does drawing resonance structures in this way for acetone produce any useful conclusions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push the electrons around in many different ways when creating a resonance structure, but some of the resulting structures will be "good" and others will be "bad." The "good" structures will contribute more to the actual properties of the molecule than the "bad" structures will.

As always, when talking about resonance structures, it's important to remember that both the name and the notation are extremely misleading. There is no vibration, oscillation, or transition between the two structures. Rather, the molecule has one structure that is a weighted average of the different structures, with the "good" structures having higher weight in the average.

The resonance structure of acetone with a formal negative charge on the oxygen and a formal positive charge on the carbon is a relatively "bad" structure (because of the formal charges) compared to the "good" one with a double bond and no formal charges. Therefore, the properties of acetone are mostly described by the "good" double-bond structure, with a much smaller contribution from the "bad" structure with formal charges.

There is actually a third possible resonance structure for acetone, where you push the pi electrons the other way. leaving the carbon negative and the oxygen positive. But this is an even more "bad" resonance structure (because oxygen is electronegative and "prefers" a negative charge) and makes an even smaller contribution to the actual properties of the molecule.

Here is another explanation (including all three possible structures for acetone) to the same effect, from Dr. Ian Hunt at Calgary: https://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/353/Carey5th/Ch01/ch1-7.html